# checkout from upstream failed to get the correct source

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

tried this `git checkout -b staging upstream/staging` but I can't get the source code of the upstream's staging branch.

Do I need to reset or I've done something wrong?
What I want is a clean copy of upstream/staging.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -b staging upstream/staging` creates a new branch named "staging" starting at the "upstream/staging" point - but `git checkout` does not pull or fetch. Have you run `git pull` from there?

Comment: if I have commit in my current branch, the changes will be into staging too, it's not sync although I checkout upstream/staging

Comment: Right - because checkout does not do anything with the remote. You need to fetch or pull.

Answer (score 0):

Update your local repository

```
# fetch all changes from remote (not a must but a best practice)
git fetch --all --prune

# now checkout the desired branch from an origin or from any other remote
git checkout -b <branch name> <remote name>/<remote branch name>
```

---

[image]

Comment: why must fetch --all? can't it be `git fetch upstream/master --prune`?

Comment: there's a reason --all is an arg right? if not why don't they don't put --all as default? git fetch doesn't include --all fetch.

Comment: `git pull` only fetch the current branch

Comment: `--all` in `fetch/pull/push` doesn't mean "all branches", it means "all remotes".

Comment: `git fetch` by default have `all remotes`? What is all remotes if it's not `all changes of all remote branch`?